# php simplexml_load_string ignores elements

Tags: php, xml, parsing, xml-parsing

maybe you can help me: I try to parse this xml file

```
<norm>

    <metadaten>
        <jurabk>GWB</jurabk>
        <enbez>§ 99</enbez>
        <titel format="XML">Öffentliche Auftraggeber</titel>
    </metadaten>

    <textdaten>

        <text format="XML">
            <Content>
                <P>Öffentliche Auftraggeber sind 
                    <DL Type="arabic">
                        <DT>1.</DT>
                        <DD Font="normal">
                            <LA>Gebietskörperschaften sowie deren Sondervermögen,</LA>
                        </DD>
                    </DL>
                </P>
            </Content>
        </text>

        <fussnoten>
            <Content>
                <P>(+++ § 99: Zur Anwendung vgl. § 41 Abs. 2 MessbG +++)</P>
            </Content>
        </fussnoten>

    </textdaten>

</norm>
```

When parsing it using:

```
$xml=simplexml_load_string($xmlStr) or die("Error: Cannot create object");

echo "<pre>";
print_r($xml);
echo "</pre>";
```

It ignores the part in "DL". The path
norm->textdaten->text->Content->P is incomplete.

The result is:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
   [metadaten] => SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
      [jurabk] => GWB
      [enbez] => § 99
      [titel] => Öffentliche Auftraggeber
    )

    [textdaten] => SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
        [text] => SimpleXMLElement Object
         (
          [@attributes] => Array
            (
              [format] => XML
            )
          [Content] => SimpleXMLElement Object
           (
             [P] => Öffentliche Auftraggeber sind
           )
         )

        [fussnoten] => SimpleXMLElement Object
         (
          [Content] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
               [P] => (+++ § 99: Zur Anwendung vgl. § 41 Abs. 2 MessbG +++)
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Do you have an idea how to parse it correctly?

Maybe the simplexml_load_string function is not able to retrieve text BETWEEN the

and the the DL??

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not ignore them. The debug output does not show all accessible data because it depends on how you access it. For example here is a difference if you use a property as a list (foreach) or a string.

In you case the problem is how SimpleXML treats text content of nodes. It returns only the content of the first text child node. In DOM here is a property `$textContent` that contains the text content of all descendant nodes. So the easiest way to fetch the text is converting the SimpleXMLElement into a DOMElement instance.

```
$xml = <<<'XML'
<div>
  <p>
    Some Text
    <dl>
      <dd>in descendant nodes</dd>
    </dl>
  </p>
</div>
XML;

$div = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
// only the first text child
var_dump((string)$div->p);  
// all text content
var_dump(dom_import_simplexml($div->p)->textContent);
```

Output:

```
string(22) "
    Some Text

  "
string(53) "
    Some Text

      in descendant nodes

  "
```

This includes whitespace nodes (node that contain only line breaks, spaces, ...). So depending on how you use the text content after that, you might need to clean it up using string functions.

## XML Snippets

If you want not just the XML but the whole node as a XML string, you can use `SimpleXMLElement::asXml()` or `DOMDocument::saveXml()`.

```
$div = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
var_dump($div->p->asXml());  

$node = dom_import_simplexml($div->p);
var_dump($node->ownerDocument->saveXml($node));
```

DOM allows for some options and saving HTML.

To save all child nodes inside the `p`, iterate `DOMNode::$childNodes`. Be aware that this includes not just elements, not text nodes, comments, ...

```
$node = dom_import_simplexml($div->p);
$result = '';
foreach ($node->childNodes as $child) {
  $result .= $node->ownerDocument->saveXml($child);
}
var_dump($result);
```

Iterating specific nodes is easy with Xpath. Look for `SimpleXMLElement::xpath()` and `DOMXpath::evaluate()`.

Comment: Thank you! Is there any way to get the either 1) the whole output between `<p>` and `</p>` (including the <dl>-tags or 2) an array of some kind which allows me to process the different contents?

Comment: I added some info to the answer. Be aware that SimpleXML is limited - it is an abstraction on top of DOM to allow for PHP syntax sugar. But because of that it hides stuff from you.

Answer (score 0):

It is because there is mixture of text and tags in xml. You have to modify your xml as its separated with tag. I have added `TEST` tag here. You can  change it by whatever you want

```
<?php
$xmlStr = '<norm>
   <metadaten>
      <jurabk>GWB</jurabk>
      <enbez>§ 99</enbez>
      <titel format="XML">Öffentliche Auftraggeber</titel>
   </metadaten>
   <textdaten>
      <text format="XML">
         <Content>
            <P>
               <TEST>Öffentliche Auftraggeber sind</TEST>
               <DL Type="arabic">
                  <DT>1.</DT>
                  <DD Font="normal">
                     <LA>Gebietskörperschaften sowie deren Sondervermögen,</LA>
                  </DD>
               </DL>
            </P>
         </Content>
      </text>
      <fussnoten>
         <Content>
            <P>(+++ § 99: Zur Anwendung vgl. § 41 Abs. 2 MessbG +++)</P>
         </Content>
      </fussnoten>
   </textdaten>
</norm>';

$xml=simplexml_load_string($xmlStr) or die("Error: Cannot create object");

echo "<pre>";
print_r($xml);
echo "</pre>";
```

check the o/p here: https://eval.in/815329

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately I can't modify the XML. Do you know any way to get the contents of "norm->textdaten->text->Content->P" as plain text?